# Return sha1() hash from couchdb

Tags: javascript, couchdb, sha1

I have some data stored in CouchDb of the form *key-value*. Basically it a tuple with a value and salt. I have created a view that return these tuples and calculate the sha1() of the *value* + *salt* on the client side using javascript. Is it possible to send the sha1() hash of *value* + *salt* directly from CouchDb as JSON? I do not wish to send the salt to the client. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest a Javascript SHA1 [1] implementation directly on CouchDB. I think you have two options:

1. Compute the checksum in the view. Query speed will be unchanged, but the view code will grow a bit.
2. Compute the checksum in a `_list` function. Query speed will be (in principle) slower, since you execute code for every row for every query; but your views can remain simple.

There is an SHA1 Javascript implementation in CouchDB! Point your browser to your Couch server, in `/_utils/script/sha1.js`. You can copy and paste the code if you want.

[1] Or consider SHA256 or SHA512 if possible.

Comment: I added a note that CouchDB has a Javascript SHA1 implementation you can use. (It is for browsers, you need it for servers, so copy & paste may be the most direct solution.)

Comment: Can we somehow get rid of the copy paste part ?